# Why ItemCollection.Groups is collection of Objects and not CollectionViewGroups?

Tags: c#, wpf

I mean are there cases when its items are not `CollectionViewGroup`?

Answer (score 1):

It would limit the use for `ItemCollection.Groups` in the future. Right now all elements might always be `CollectionViewGroup` and if you need to use the interface you can cast objects to an instance of `CollectionViewGroup`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to create an interface `ICollectionViewGroup` and make `ItemCollection.Groups` a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ICollectionViewGroup>`? This would reduce costs of boxing/unboxing...